# Would it be possible to genetically engineer wings onto humans?

Tags: genetics, wings

This is entirely hypothetical, but there is human gene editing equipment. It is hypothetical because the wings would not work, unless they were ultra-light and the wingspan was 60 feet.

Comment: (1) It is not logically self-contradictory. (2) It doesn't break any fundamental law of physics. (3) Therefore it is obviously *possible*.  Maybe it is not practical, maybe it is very difficult, maybe it requires knowledge which we don't yet have. But *possible* it certainly is. (4) The question would be much better if you explained why you think that it is impossible or what is the specific difficulty which you can't figure out how to overcome or work around. (5) But then you have the problem of finding some use for the wings; humans are too heavy to use any reasonably sized wings for flying.

Comment: I say it is hypothetical because the wings, although we would have them, would be virtually useless, and maybe a hindrance.

Comment: If you're postulating a low-gravity environment.... Could you give us a bit more context and a bit about your aims (ie. worldbuilding stuff)?

Comment: What if i also added air sacs like birds have?

Comment: Greetings Wulfbayne!  I think you'd do very well to review this forum's [tour] and [help] and [find out what worldbuilding is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before asking questions!  The reasons this poor question is being negabombed and in the close queue is that it is very poorly written. Please edit to make your question clear; write a clear and concise background description of the fictional world you're working with & the overall scientific / technical / metaphysical "level" your people at at; and then ...

Comment: (cont) ... write out some key criteria by which you'd consider a response to be a good answer to your worldbuilding problem. Keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum and it's not a brainstorming session. Don't keep tossing out ideas here in the comments. Gather your thoughts, put them in order, and then edit them into your query so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bird people *maybe*, but not angels.

It's virtually impossible to put working wings on a human, and have them continue to look anything remotely human.

Even if you were to get past the wingspan weight problem there is a much larger barrier, muscle placement.

Humans have arms, and we often think of the arm muscles being in the arms, but that's not true. The most important muscles for the arms are in our chest and back.

Another set of appendages, be it extra arms, legs, or wings would need a similar amount of support muscles on the torso. As a human looks right now there is simply nowhere to put them and still look human.

So the best we can do is modify arms into wings. Problem is now if you need a huge wingspan, you need arms to be that long. You probably also need to modify most of the human biology to lower the weight. At the end you are going to end up with something that most likely does not even remotely look or seem human anymore.